# Method to replicate sqlite database across multiple servers

Tags: sqlite, replication, distributed-computing, high-availability, rethinkdb

I'm developing an application that works distributed, and I have a SQLite database that must be shared between distributed servers.
If I'm in serverA, and change sqlite row, this change must be in the other servers instantly, but if a server were offline and then it came online, it must update all info equal other servers.

I'm trying to develop a HA service with small SQLite databases.

I'm thinking on something like MongoDB or ReThinkDB, due to replication works fine and I have got data independently server online I had.

There are a library or other SQL methodology to share data between servers?

Comment: No considerations about race conditions or other types of conflict?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I used the Raft consensus protocol to replicate my SQLite database. You can find the system here:

https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite

Comment: is the JSON1 extension available with rqlite?

Comment: Looks amazing. Looking forward to trying it.

Comment: I wanted to try this but I need a drop-in replacement for SQLite. RQLite requires you use its HTTP API when executing the sql statements.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some options:

[LiteReplica](http://litereplica.io):

It supports master-slave replication for SQLite3 databases using a single master (writable node) and one or many replicas (read-only nodes).

If a device went offline and then it came online, the secondary/slave dbs are updated with the primary/master one incrementally.

[LiteSync](http://litesync.io):

It implements multi-master replication so we can write to the db in any node, even when the device is off-line.

On both we open the database using a modified URI, like this:

```
  “file:/path/to/app.db?replica=master&bind=tcp://0.0.0.0:4444”
```

[AergoLite](https://aergolite.aergo.io):

Blockchain based, it has the highest level of security. Stores immutable relational data, secured by a distributed consensus with low resource usage.

Disclosure: I am the author of these solutions

Comment: Would this work for many to one? Meaning I have many sources (same layout/tables) to one single slave?

Comment: No, it works with a single master. It will not merge data from many sources on a single db, but you can keep a separate replica for each source.

Comment: Hi, very interested in these especially LiteSync. We have a situation where multiple high latency locations need to write to a local database and sync to a master database. It is not ideal or necessary to keep all the data in the main database in each location, so we're looking for more of a "one way" sync, Do you know a good solution for this?

Comment: One way sync from secondary to primary nodes? Maybe [OctoDB](https://github.com/octodb/docs). BTW this is not the place for queries

Answer (score 6):

You can synchronize SQLite databases by embedding [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/download) in your application.  It supports occasionally connected clients, so it will capture changes and sync them when a server comes online.  It supports several different database platforms and can be used as a library or as a standalone service.

Comment: Is there a way to synchronize divergent file-hosted SQLite databases?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CopyCat](http://copycat.fr), which support SQLite as well as a few other database types.

Comment: Apparently it only supports SQLite under very limited conditions (e.g. using Delphi?!)

Answer (score 1):

Marmot looks good:

https://github.com/maxpert/marmot

From their docs:

## What & Why?

Marmot is a distributed SQLite replicator with leaderless, and eventual consistency. It allows you to build a robust replication between your nodes by building on top of fault-tolerant NATS Jetstream. This means if you are running a read heavy website based on SQLite, you should be easily able to scale it out by adding more SQLite replicated nodes. SQLite is probably the most ubiquitous DB that exists almost everywhere, Marmot aims to make it even more ubiquitous for server side applications by building a replication layer on top.